# How does Varnish cache handle different domains?

Tags: cache, reverse-proxy, varnish

I just started reading about Varnish and am considering using it as a frontend to my webservers. I have multiple domains on my webserver that fetch the same content when the same query strings are used. So lets say one client visits:

```
http://domain1.com/script.php?string1=abc&string2=123
```

And later on, someone else visits:

```
http://domain2.com/script.php?string1=abc&string2=123
```

Would Varnish cache the results from the first visit and use that for the second client? Thanks!

**EDIT:** After some more reading, it sounds like the following may work:

```
sub vcl_hash {
    set req.hash += req.url;
    return (hash);
}
```

So instead of added the http.host variable to the hash, it ignores it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure it to do so, sort-of. By default, it won't (and shouldn't).

From [Varnish FAQ/HowDoI](http://varnish.projects.linpro.no/wiki/FAQ#HowdoI)

> I have a site with many hostnames, how
>   do I keep them from multiplying the
>   cache?
>
> You can do this by normalizing the
>   "Host" header for all your hostnames.
>   Here's a VCL example:
>
> `if (req.http.host ~ "^(www.)?example.com")
>   {   set req.http.host = "example.com"; }`

Comment: That or it's probably possible to strip the hostname entirely and just use the remainder of the path. YMMV.

Comment: Hmm, I added some code above that may work. If anyone can confirm, that'd be great!

Comment: I don't think (or don't hope) that Lin is asking about how to share the cache.  The problem is that sharing the same data across urls on different sites could be a security/integrity issue.  http://www.example.com/bobs_friends/ is NOT the same as http://www.example2.com/bobs_friends/.  Serving one when the other is asked for could be disastrous.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 domains on my VM, I am using Nginx and Varnish, currently I am on a pre prod configuration, here what I am doing :

```
NGINX:80 ==> VARNISH:8080 ==> NGINX:8081
```

I am using Nginx:80 like a proxy IF the domain needs Varnish, if not, I use FastCGI stuff. In this exemple, the not Varnish sites are not concerned by Varnish. It looks stupid but it woks ;-) and none of my customers complain (yet....).